Rudin $8.18$ theorem.
There are necessary definitions and theorem for the proof:



here is the theorem:
If $1\lt p \lt \infty$ and $f \in L^{p}(R^k)$ then $Mf \in L^{p}(R^k)$
there is its proof:
Since $Mf = M(|f|)$ we may assume, without loss of generality, that $f \geq 0$.  Theorem $7.4$ shows that there is a constant $A$, depending only on the dimension $k$, such that $$m\{Mg \gt t\} \leq \frac{A}{t} ||g||_{1} $$ for every $g \in L^{1}(R^k)$. Pick a constant $c, \ 0 \lt c \lt 1$, which will be specified later so as to minimize a certain upper bound. For each $t \in (0, \infty)$, split $f$ into a sum $$f = g_t + h_t $$  where $ g_t(x) = f(x)$ if $f(x) \gt ct $ and if $f(x) \leq ct$ then it is equal to $0$. Then $0 \leq h_t(x) \leq ct$ for every $x \in R^k$. Hence $h_t \in L^{\infty}, Mh_t \leq ct$, and $Mf \leq Mg_t + Mh_t \leq Mg_t + ct$. If $(Mf)(x) \gt t$ for some $x$, it follows that $$(Mg_t)(x) \gt (1-c)t. $$  Setting $E_t = \{ f \gt ct\}$, we get $m\{Mf \gt t\} \leq m\{Mg_t \gt (1-c)t \} \leq \frac{A}{(1-c)t} ||g_t||_1 = \frac{A}{(1-c)t} \int_{E_i} f dm .$  We now use Theorem $8.16$, with $X = R^k, \mu = m, \phi(t) = t^p$, to calculate
$\int_{R^k} (Mf)^p dm = p \int_0^{\infty} m\{Mf \gt t \} t^{p-1} dt \leq \frac{Ap}{1-c} \int_0^{\infty} t^{p-2} dt \int_{E_i} f dm = \frac{Ap}{1-c} \int_{R^k} f dm \int_0^{f/c} t^{p-2} dt = \frac{Apc^{1-p}}{(1-c)(p-1)} \int_{R^k} f^{p} dm. $
This proves the theorem.
I don't understand how do we get that $\frac{Ap}{1-c} \int_0^{\infty} t^{p-2} dt \int_{E_i} f dm$ is equal to $ \frac{Ap}{1-c} \int_{R^k} f dm \int_0^{f/c} t^{p-2} dt$ and therefore I also don't understand why is the former equal to  $ \frac{Apc^{1-p}}{(1-c)(p-1)} \int_{R^k} f^{p} dm.$
Any help would be appreciated.

As he changes the order of integration, try to apply Fubini's theorem.


I don't understand how do we get that $\frac{Ap}{1-c} \int_0^{\infty} t^{p-2} dt \int_{E_i} f dm$ is equal to $ \frac{Ap}{1-c} \int_{R^k} f dm \int_0^{f/c} t^{p-2} dt$

It is by application of the Fubini theorem. Write $\int_0^\infty t^{p-2}\, dt \int_{E_t} f\, dm = \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} t^{p-2}f(x) \chi_{E_t}(x)\, dm\, dt$ and note that $\chi_{E_t}(x) = \chi_{[0, f(x)/c)} (t)$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $t > 0$. Then by Fubini, $$\int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} t^{p-2} f(x) \chi_{E_t}(x)\, dm\, dt = \int_{\mathbb{R}^k} \int_0^\infty t^{p-2} f(x)\chi_{[0, f(x)/c)}\, dt\, dm = \int_\mathbb{R^k} f dm \int_0^{f/c} t^{p-2}\, dt$$
